# How do I properly set aliases in a bash script (Ubuntu 17.04)?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have this script called `menal` in my `~/bin` directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

alias mendir='cd ~/projects/myproject'
```

It has executable property and I expect that when I run it it sets an appropiate alias for `cd` command for the terminal session. But it doesn't. When I type `$ menal` in terminal it shows no error, but when I try `$ mendir` after that I get

```
No command 'mendir' found, did you mean:
 Command 'menhir' from package 'menhir' (universe)
mendir: command not found
```

When I type

```
$ alias mendir='cd ~/projects/myproject'
$ mendir
```

in terminal, it works.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a script scope issue or something?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but I think it will answer the question of why your alias is not being persisted - https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a scope problem. Calling it the following way won't produce the result you expect:

`./bin/menal`

If you want the alias to persist, use `source`:

`source ./bin/menal`

Comment: To persist [within the current shell]. If the OP opens a new terminal, they will need to `source` the file again.

Comment: Add `source ~/bin/menal` to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: @ephemeris - for that, take a look at [suraj's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj).

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your `.bash_profile`.

```
alias mendir='cd ~/projects/myproject'
```

then do `source ~/.bash_profile`

It should create the alias and also will work on every login.

Comment: There is no real need to add this to the users bashrc or profile - as long as the file is sourced at the correct point in time it can be located anywhere.

Comment: True..OP was trying to set an alias..This would have made it persistent..